# BigQuery Table Design - Mix Fact and Dimension Tables?

Tags: google-bigquery, denormalization

I'm planning to store multiple dimension tables in BigQuery. 
In a normalized design I would have fact tables containing foreign keys that refer to one or many of the dimension tables.

I've read a bit about denormalization, and I'm wondering how far I should go. In general, do people mix fact and dimension data together into one table in BigQuery?

Regarding nested fields:
In case a single fact refers to multiple dimension tables, would you have a nested column in each of the dimension tables, or just one fact table and then use joins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In general, do people mix fact and dimension data together into one table in BigQuery?

Yes!

> In case a single fact refers to multiple dimension tables, would you have a nested column in each of the dimension tables, or just one fact table and then use joins?

You should nest your dimention data inside fact data, not vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Off-topic question, to me it seems unusual to query tables like this (e.g. show me all customers who have at least 5 records of type XYZ in the fact table). Can you point me to any guide where I can learn to query denormalized tables?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I often mix fact and dimension data within BigQuery.  I find this works well for tables that get rebuilt often.

I'm more cautious about adding dimension attributes to large, date-partitioned tables.  I start asking questions like these when working with large date-partitioned tables...if a dimension's attribute changes, do I reload all date partitions, only the last N days, etc.